# SQL Statement DATEPART Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is wrong with this SQL statement? I keep getting SelMonth and CurMonth are invalid columns, am I doing my Where clause wrong? Is the DATEPART causing a problem here?

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
   EName, EDate, EDateEnd, 
   DATEPART(month, EDate) AS SelMonth, 
   DATEPART(month, { fn CURDATE() }) AS CurMonth
FROM         
   Events
WHERE     
   (EDate >= { fn CURDATE() }) 
   AND (SelMonth = CurMonth)
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @BryanS. SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the SelMonth and CurMonth in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
       EName, EDate, EDateEnd, 
       DATEPART(month, EDate) AS SelMonth, 
       DATEPART(month, { fn CURDATE() }) AS CurMonth
FROM   Events
WHERE  (EDate >= { fn CURDATE() }) 
       AND (DATEPART(month, EDate) = DATEPART(month, { fn CURDATE() }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SelMonth and CurMonth are derived columns they will not be available in the current level of query.
Option 1 : CTE (For SQL 2005 and above)

```
WITH evnts AS
(SELECT ename, 
        edate, 
        edateend, 
        Datepart(MONTH, edate)            AS selmonth, 
        Datepart(MONTH, { fn CURDATE() }) AS curmonth 
 FROM   events)
SELECT TOP (5) * 
  FROM  evnts
 WHERE   (EDate >= { fn CURDATE() }) AND (SelMonth = CurMonth)
```

Option 2 : Inline View

```
SELECT TOP (5) * FROM
(SELECT ename, 
        edate, 
        edateend, 
        Datepart(MONTH, edate)            AS selmonth, 
        Datepart(MONTH, { fn CURDATE() }) AS curmonth 
 FROM   events)

WHERE     (EDate >= { fn CURDATE() }) AND (SelMonth = CurMonth)
```